# Specializing method calls in order in meta-programming

Tags: julia

I have issue after calling my macro:

```
@introspectable square(x) = x * x
```

Then when calling 
    square(3) 
i should be able to get 9, cause the function call has been specialized to execute an attribute of the structure which is Julia code, however when I enter the macro, the code seems to be directly evaluated.

What i have tried:

```
struct IntrospectableFunction
  name
  parameters
  native_function
end


(f::IntrospectableFunction)(x) = f.native_function(x)

macro introspectable(expr)
  name = expr.args[1].args[1]
  parameters = tuple(expr.args[1].args[2:end]...)
  body = expr.args[2].args[2]

:( global $name  = IntrospectableFunction( :( name ), $parameters, :( body ) ))
end

@introspectable square(x) = x * x
square(3)
```

The answer should be 9 , however i get  "Object of type symbol are not callable ". However if i replace  :( body ) with x -> x * x i get the desired result, my objective is generalizing the macro-call.

Answer (score 3):

I usually find it easier to work with expressions in macros (it is not the shortest way to write things, but, from my experience, it is much easier to control what gets generated).

Therefore I would rewrite your code as:

```
macro introspectable(expr)
    name = expr.args[1].args[1]
    parameters = expr.args[1].args[2:end]
    anon = Expr(Symbol("->"), Expr(:tuple, parameters...), expr.args[2].args[2])
    constr = Expr(:call, :IntrospectableFunction, QuoteNode(name), Tuple(parameters), anon)
    esc(Expr(:global, Expr(Symbol("="), name, constr)))
end
```

Now, as you said you wanted generality I would define your functor like this:

```
(f::IntrospectableFunction)(x...) = f.native_function(x...)
```

(in this way you allow multiple positional arguments to be passed).

Now let us test our definitions:

```
julia> @introspectable square(x) = x * x
IntrospectableFunction(:square, (:x,), getfield(Main, Symbol("##3#4"))())

julia> square(3)
9

julia> @macroexpand @introspectable square(x) = x * x
:(global square = IntrospectableFunction(:square, (:x,), ((x,)->x * x)))

julia> @introspectable toarray(x,y) = [x,y]
IntrospectableFunction(:toarray, (:x, :y), getfield(Main, Symbol("##5#6"))())

julia> toarray("a", 10)
2-element Array{Any,1}:
   "a"
 10

julia> @macroexpand @introspectable toarray(x,y) = [x,y]
:(global toarray = IntrospectableFunction(:toarray, (:x, :y), ((x, y)->[x, y])))

julia> function localscopetest()
       @introspectable globalfun(x...) = x
       end
localscopetest (generic function with 1 method)

julia> localscopetest()
IntrospectableFunction(:globalfun, (:(x...),), getfield(Main, Symbol("##9#10"))())

julia> globalfun(1,2,3,4,5)
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

julia> function f()
       v = 100
       @introspectable localbinding(x) = (v, x)
       end
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f()
IntrospectableFunction(:localbinding, (:x,), getfield(Main, Symbol("##11#12")){Int64}(100))

julia> localbinding("x")
(100, "x")
```

(note that it is useful to use `@macroexpand` to make sure our macro works as expected)

#### EDIT - how to handle a minimal multiple dispatch

I am writing a non-macro example because it is related to the data structure:

Use e.g. such a definition:

```
struct IntrospectableFunction
  name::Symbol
  method_array::Vector{Pair{Type{<:Tuple}, Function}}
end

function (f::IntrospectableFunction)(x...)
    for m in f.method_array
        if typeof(x) <: first(m)
            return last(m)(x...)
        end
    end
    error("signature not found")
end
```

and now you can write:

```
julia> square = IntrospectableFunction(:square, [Tuple{Any}=>x->x*x,Tuple{Any,Any}=>(x,y)->x*y])
IntrospectableFunction(:square, Pair{DataType,Function}[Tuple{Any}=>##9#11(), Tuple{Any,Any}=>##10#12()])

julia> square(3)
9

julia> square(2,3)
6
```

Keep in mind that the approach I present is not perfect and universal - it just serves to give a very simple example how you could do it.

Comment: Thank you, this  has been really helpful and clarifying.

Comment: lets say, i wanted to overload for example have 2 methods,  square(x) = x * x and square(x,y) = x * y . How would you do ?

Comment: I will comment in the answer but you are getting to a point where you want to reimplement method dispatch mechanics in Julia.